# elegantly splitting a list (or dict) into two via some arbitrary function in python

Tags: python, select, dictionary, list-comprehension

Is there any elegant way of splitting a list/dict into two lists/dicts in python, taking in some arbitrary splitter function?

I could easily have two list comprehensions, or two selects, but it seems to me there should be some better way of doing it that avoids iterating over every element twice.

I could do it easily with a for loop and if statement, but that takes something like 7 lines of code for what should be a very simple operation.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Just for reference, my two solutions would be,

```
# given dict cows, mapping cow names to weight
# fast solution
fatcows = {}
thincows = {}
for name, weight in cows:
    if weight < 100:
        thincows[name] = weight
    else:
        fatcows[name] = weight

# double-list-comprehension solution would be
fatcows = {name: weight for name, weight in cows.items() if weight > 100}
thincows = {name: weight for name, weight in cows.items() if weight < 100}
```

I was thinking there must be something more elegant than this that i never thought of, something like:

```
thincows, fatcows = ??? short expression involving cows ???
```

I know it's possible to do by writing higher order functions stuff to do it for me, and i know how to do it manually. I was just wondering if there was some super-elegant language feature to do it for me.

It's like you can write your own subroutines and whatnot to do a SELECT on a list, or you can just say

```
thincows = select(cows, lambda c: c.weight < 100)
```

I was hoping there would be some similarly elegant way of *splitting* the list, with one pass

Comment: Can you give an example of the arbitrary splitter function you mention?  Even better, show an example that you'd like to tighten up.

Comment: Could you add your seven lines of code?

Comment: Scrolling through the answers, was shocked not to see itertools.ifilter-- figured I'd misunderstood (another) itertools function since your question sounded like another of the "Is there a better way to do (insert itertools function remade by me here)?", which seem to come up a lot.  But then was relieved to see answer by superuser at bottom to that effect.  You should accept adam rosenfeld's answer, since it's the python standard library way of doing what you want. Gratz on such a popular question for one of your first!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More fun with cows :)

```
import random; random.seed(42)
cows = {n:random.randrange(50,150) for n in 'abcdefghijkl'}

thin = {}
for name, weight in cows.iteritems():
    thin.setdefault(weight < 100, {})[name] = weight

>>> thin[True]
{'c': 77, 'b': 52, 'd': 72, 'i': 92, 'h': 58, 'k': 71, 'j': 52}

>>> thin[False]
{'a': 113, 'e': 123, 'l': 100, 'g': 139, 'f': 117}
```

Comment: Nice, i really like this one =)

Answer (score 6):

How about 3 lines?

```
fatcows, thincows = {}, {}
for name, weight in cows.items():
    (fatcows if weight > 50 else thincows)[name] = weight
```

Tested:

```
>>> cows = {'bessie':53, 'maud':22, 'annabel': 77, 'myrna':43 }
>>> fatcows, thincows = {}, {}
>>> for name, weight in cows.items():
...     (fatcows if weight > 50 else thincows)[name] = weight
... 
>>> fatcows
{'annabel': 77, 'bessie': 53}
>>> thincows
{'maud': 22, 'myrna': 43}
```

Answer (score 5):

Any solution is going to take O(N) time to compute, whether it be through two passes through the list or one pass that does more work per item.  The simplest way is just to use the tools that are available to you: [`itertools.ifilter`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) and [`itertools.ifilterfalse`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilterfalse):

```
def bifurcate(predicate, iterable):
    """Returns a tuple of two lists, the first of which contains all of the
       elements x of `iterable' for which predicate(x) is True, and the second
       of which contains all of the elements x of `iterable` for which
       predicate(x) is False."""
    return (itertools.ifilter(predicate, iterable),
            itertools.ifilterfalse(predicate, iterable))
```

Comment: My vote goes to this answer.  Apparently ifilter isn't as well known as say, the more confusing (to me) groupby.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with a genex, sorting, and `itertools.groupby()`, but it will probably not be much more efficient than the brute-force solution.

#### Brute-force solution:

```
def bifurcate(pred, seq):
  if pred is None:
    pred = lambda x: x
  res1 = []
  res2 = []
  for i in seq:
    if pred(i):
      res1.append(i)
    else:
      res2.append(i)
  return (res2, res1)
```

#### Elegant solution:

```
import itertools
import operator

def bifurcate(pred, seq):
  if pred is None:
    pred = lambda x: x
  return tuple([z[1] for z in y[1]] for y in
    itertools.groupby(sorted((bool(pred(x)), x) for x in seq),
    operator.itemgetter(0)))
```

Comment: Your brute-force solution will be more efficient than your 'elegant' solution. Brute does a single pass, and elegant performs a sort (and more).

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple, without any outside tools:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4]
list_a = []
list_b = []

def my_function(num):
    return num % 2

generator = (list_a.append(item) if my_function(item) else list_b.append(item)\
        for item in my_list)
for _ in generator:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, its about cows :)

```
cows = {'a': 123, 'b': 90, 'c': 123, 'd': 70}

select = lambda cows, accept: {name: weight for name, weight
                               in cows.items()
                               if accept(weight)}

thin = select(cows, lambda x: x < 100)
fat  = select(cows, lambda x: x > 100)
```

Comment: Don't name your function `select` -- `select` is also the name of the [`select` module](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html), which is a rather important module for doing efficient non-polling I/O on multiple file descriptors simultaneously.